# How to reduce gap between bootstrap columns

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have this code which displayes 4 items in a row. I have given the columns border to give you an idea about the size of each column.
Inside each column there is a wrapper of fixed width and height which displays the image and text. Now is it possible to reduce the gap between columns for large devices ?
https://jsfiddle.net/3j6x1fou/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .green {
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
        .blue {
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }
        .orange{
            border: 1px solid orange;
        }
        .yellow {
            border: 1px solid yellow;
        }

        .size {

        }

        .wrapper {
            width: 180px;
            height: 200px;
        }

        .inherit {
            width: inherit;
            height: inherit;
        }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 mt-5 mt-md-0 green">
            <div class="wrapper" style="margin: 0 auto;">
            <img class="img-fluid inherit" src="https://i.redd.it/dkcm8of8x9b01.jpg"> 
            <div>Xtres Watch R007</div>     
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 mt-5 mt-md-0 blue">
            <div class="wrapper" style="margin: 0 auto;">
           <img class="img-fluid inherit" src="https://i.redd.it/dkcm8of8x9b01.jpg">
           <div>Xtres Watch R007</div>         
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 mt-5 mt-md-0 orange">
            <div class="wrapper" style="margin: 0 auto;">
          <img class="img-fluid inherit" src="https://i.redd.it/dkcm8of8x9b01.jpg">
          <div>Xtres Watch R007</div>         
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 mt-5 mt-md-0 yellow">
            <div class="wrapper" style="margin: 0 auto;">
          <img class="img-fluid inherit" src="https://i.redd.it/dkcm8of8x9b01.jpg">
          <div>Xtres Watch R007</div>         
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I suppose when you say **gap** you refer to the space between each column right? If so, Bootstrap does not provide a way to alter the size of this space, it does provide the [`no-gutters`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#no-gutters) class that can be added to a `row` to *remove* the gap between columns, but that's about it, unless you are willing to create classes that alter the `padding` and `margins` of the columns, which I wouldn't recommend. You can also use Bootstrap [spacing utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/) to somewhat do what you need

You might be able to achieve what you need using CSS Grid, you can pretty much define the same layout without using Bootstrap's columns and you actually have a `grid-gap` property which you can use to define the size you want for those spaces.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>
```